# an unhandled exception of type system.nullreferenceexception occurred

Tags: c#, web

I getting this error: `an unhandled exception of type 'system.nullreferenceexception' occurred`

I trying to build a auto updater for some website..
This web not have a Form tag it's working with java script.
What the code needs to do it's to get into the site automatic.

In this code:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
            {
                if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("button"))
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
                if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("text"))
                {
                    el.SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
                }
                if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("password"))
                {
                    el.SetAttribute("value", BaseString + Match[Count]);
                }
            }
```

What I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: Well presumably one of those elements doesn't have one of those attributes...

Comment: One of the objects is null - BaseString or Match[]?

Comment: I put my 2 cents on the last SetAttribute. GetAttribute should return empty string not nulls. But the de-bug-gers exists for these situations.

Comment: Thanks every one but all the objects isn't null